# Detect IE in expressjs, but can't get static files

Tags: node.js, express

I've tried to detect IE by using expressjs, the code surely redirect me to the error page.

But the problem is that it won't render css files and get image files in my folder.

I think the problem is that expressjs redirect to `error_page` before the static path is set.

So I put `app.all('*', ieRedirecter);`, after

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
```

The problem is still occur... could someone help me out, thanks!

My settings

```
function ieRedirecter(req, res, next) {
  if(req.headers['user-agent'].indexOf("MSIE") >= 0) {
    var myNav = req.headers['user-agent'];
    var IEbrowser = parseInt(myNav.split('MSIE')[1]) 
    if(IEbrowser < 9) {
      res.render('error/browser_error', {title : 'not supporting your browser'})
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    app.use(app.router);

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));

    app.all('*', ieRedirecter);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This order doesn't work:

```
app.use(app.router);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));

app.all('*', ieRedirecter);
```

`app.router` is the middleware that handles all your routing requests, including `app.all()`, even though you declare that route after your other middleware (fun fact: at any moment you declare a route – using `app.{get,post,all,...}` – the `app.router` middleware is inserted into the middleware chain automatically).

If possible, the easiest solution would be to move the static and IE middleware to before your routes (but I realize that might cause problems with your application setup):

```
// static middleware first...
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'))

// ...followed by the IE check
app.use(ieRedirecter);

// ...followed by your routes
app.get('/', ...);
...
```

Another solution would be filter out requests for static resources in your `ieRedirecter` middleware  by looking at `req.path`, but that assumes that you can easily identify those requests (like if they start with `/css` or `/js`).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I've clarify some questions by your answers. And I've just solved the problem after reading through your answer, thanks again!